# How to trace all changes to a box

Tags: debugging, sourcecode

I'm currently knee-deep in debugging a mysterious bug in my daily usage of TeX. I have a fairly substantial list of packages that I use all at the same time, and I can't seem to track down the cause of my bug.

The problem boils down to that at some point, the box `\footins` gets changed from void to an empty box, which trips up dblfnote in the output routine. I've tried valiantly to see where this is set, but to no avail.

`\tracingassigns` did not help, for some reasons. So I'm looking for some way to track every change to `\box\footins`, so I can see where the errant code is.

I wish I could put up a MWE, but the error condition is rather mysterious to me, so I can only really ask for this particular approach.

Comment: not sure you can trace an insert box using normal tracing. I'd stare at `\@reinserts` although that is designed not to make a void box non-void, some package may have interfered...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use multicols, so I redefined `\reinsert@footnotes` to match the normal `\@reinserts`, and that fixed the problem. I have no idea why, though. Maybe I'll ask another question about that macro...

Comment: if you can make a small mwe you could use the latexbug package and submit it to the bug tracker at latex-project.org, let Frank have a look at the multicols code.

Answer (score 3):

You can put some "trace" commands from place to place. For instance:

```
\newcounter{test}
\newcommand\test{%
  \stepcounter{test}%
  \ifvoid\footins
    \message{^^JStill void at point number \thetest}
  \else
    \message{^^JNon void at point number \thetest}
  \fi
}
\test
\documentclass{article}
\test
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\test
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\test
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\test
\usepackage{geometry}
\test
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\test

\begin{document}
\test
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

The compilation report and log file show 8 messages "Still void at point number ...".